# How to estimate NetworkX graph memory usage?

Tags: python, memory, networkx

How to check the amount of memory used by a NetworkX graph?

There is a method for checking the number of nodes and edges, but I could not find one for memory usage?

Comment: https://groups.google.com/g/networkx-discuss/c/Etd4GpkjPdA

Comment: accepted answer is not correct anymore for latest release 2.16 of networkx. Bill the Lizard answer is better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get an estimate by adding up the size of the edge list and the size of the node list:

```
 sys.getsizeof(G.edge) + sys.getsizeof(G.node)
```

Comment: Is there any reason why expected behavior could be different in NetworkX v2.1? With an empty `MultiDiGraph`,  get a size of `112` when summing `sys.getsizeof(G.edges) + sys.getsizeof(G.node)`. result is the same with a large network graph as well.

Comment: nx-2.1 graphs do not have the `.edge` attribute anymore. You cannot compare 1.11 `.edge` and 2.1 `.edges`.

Comment: Right... I returned the `.edges(data=True)` object in an attempt to replicate the difference but this to was unsuccessful (I think the 2.x edges is a generator). My solution was to iterate through each edge in `.edges(data=True)` and load in the data.

Answer (score 6):

In NetworkX 2.0 and later, `G.edges` and `G.nodes` return iterators, so taking the size of those directly doesn't work, it just gives you the size of the iterator objects. You need it iterate over those objects and get the size of each edge and node and sum those to estimate the memory used by the graph.

```
import networkx as nx
import sys

G = nx.Graph()
# populate the graph with nodes and edges

edge_mem = sum([sys.getsizeof(e) for e in G.edges])
node_mem = sum([sys.getsizeof(n) for n in G.nodes])

print("Edge memory:", edge_mem)
print("Node memory:", node_mem)
print("Total memory:", edge_mem + node_mem)
```

Comment: This gives the correct estimate about the size of the graph.
sys.getsizeof(G.edge) + sys.getsizeof(G.node) as in the expected answer (even with correct call : G.edges, G.nodes does not give the correct estimate.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer at this point. It might also be worth pointing out that this returns the size in bytes. :)