# Size of networkx.Graph() object?

Tags: python, networkx

I have pandas dataframe with 2 columns: `col1`, `col2`. 
`sys.getsizeof(dataframe)` shows 495137153 bytes.

Then i grow a graph:

```
G = networkx.Graph()
G.add_edges_from(zip(data['col1'], data['col2']))
```

And now i want to check size of my graph, but `sys.getsizeof(G)` show 64 bytes

How to get real size of object G?

Update: I checked size of `G.edges` + size `G.nodes`, it's about 0.2 GB. But growing graph adds ~5 GB to my used RAM. Why so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can estimate the size by adding the size of edge list and node list as shown below. The answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42613681/networkx-graph-memory-usage)

> sys.getsizeof(G.edge) + sys.getsizeof(G.node)

Comment: hm, after using `G.add_edges_from(zip(data['col1'], data['col2']))` i got ~+5GB used ram, but sum of edges and nodes are about 0.2GB.